# Return Array from Embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, embedded-database, embedded-documents

I have a data like in mongodb collection name property.

```
{
            "_id": "593a3d828e2ef100d1496e77",
            "feature_type": "house",
            "features": [
                {
                    "name": "h1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "h2"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I want only

```
 [
            {
                "name": "h1"
            },
            {
                "name": "h2"
            }
        ]
```

as result i tried this by

```
req.db.collection('FeatureSettings').findOne({feature_type: req.params.feature_type}, {features: 1});
```

this give

```
{
    "_id": "593a3d828e2ef100d1496e77",
    "features": [
        {
            "name": "Hotel"
        },
        {
            "name": "Apartment"
        }
    ]
}
```

what can i do to get result as given above.

Comment: Don't even try really. Just use it as it is. There is nothing wrong with it and the only way to do it adds a significant cost to processing. Simple queries are fast. So accept that this is how you get it and just access the array by the presented path in the returned structure.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am going to make api for public so returned structure is also a point. :)

Comment: Pay attention to the answers you are getting. Everyone is telling you to access the property from the returned document. This is the correct thing to do. Don't ask the database to do it, because it really should not. If you wanted the content separately, then it should not be an embedded document.

Comment: ya i am thinking about that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using something like mongoose [that returns promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), you could use the result of the query

```
return req.db.collection('FeatureSettings')
.findOne({feature_type: req.params.feature_type}, {features: 1})
.then((result) => {
    return result.features;
});
```

Comment: i am not using mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the _id from your projection like here:

```
req.db.collection('FeatureSettings').findOne({feature_type: req.params.feature_type}, {features: 1, _id:0});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to return only `features` array values.

```
req.db.collection('FeatureSettings')
 .findOne({feature_type: req.params.feature_type}, {features:1, _id:0}).features;
```

**OR**

```
// if you use mongoose can use 
return req.db.collection('FeatureSettings')
  .findOne({feature_type: req.params.feature_type}, {features:1, _id:0})
  .exec()
  .then((result) => {
     return result.features;
  });
```

Comment: i am not using mongoose.

Comment: second part for `mongoose` but first part should work for `native mongodb`  @manoj